# Arguments and reference

Tags: javascript

Consider this JavaScript function:

```
var f = function (a) {
  console.log(a+" "+arguments[0]);
  a = 3;
  console.log(a+" "+arguments[0]);
}
```

I would expect that `a` and `arguments[0]` reference the same value only up to the second statement of the function. Instead they appear to always refer the same value: `f(2)` causes

```
2 2
3 3
```

and `f({foo: 'bar'})` causes:

```
[object Object] [object Object]
3 3
```

Are argument identifiers and the `arguments` identifier linked in a special way?

Comment: Yes, and it's a bad thing and I think that is going to change anyway.

Comment: This is a duplicate I think, I'm sure this is referenced somewhere..I'll try and dig it out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: @Liam: How is that a duplicate of this question?

Comment: `I would expect that a and arguments[0] reference the same value only up to the second statement of the function. Instead they appear to always refer the same value`, i.e. they are reference types...Also your answer basically says, this is a reference type.

Comment: @Liam: Well, the linked question talks more about how values/variables are treated in general, doesn't it? `arguments` is a special case. JavaScript is still pass-by-value. It's impossible to recreate the behavior of `arguments` in user-land code.

Comment: Well, no, because they behave in the same manner, i.e. there are referencing the same memory. It's the same thing. `This means that changing the property changes the corresponding value of the argument binding and vice-versa.`

Comment: @Liam: I'm not denying that. I'm just saying that the linked question covers a different topic. The linked question is about how values are passed *to* functions. This question is about how `arguments` behaves. Slightly related, but yet different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are argument identifiers and the arguments identifier linked in a special way?

Yes (but only in non-strict mode).

From the specification ([ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6), [ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6)):

> For non-strict mode functions the integer indexed data properties of an `arguments` object whose numeric name values are less than the number of formal parameters of the corresponding function object initially share their values with the corresponding argument bindings in the function’s [execution context](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-execution-contexts). **This means that changing the property changes the corresponding value of the argument binding and vice-versa.** This correspondence is broken if such a property is deleted and then redefined or if the property is changed into an accessor property. For strict mode functions, the values of the arguments object’s properties are simply a copy of the arguments passed to the function and there is no dynamic linkage between the property values and the formal parameter values.